# How to change the path of application in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I removed **phonegap** from

```
/usr/local/bin/phonegap
```

and installed it again using `npm`, now when running `phonegap`, I see this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phonegap: No such file or directory
```

while `phonegap` is installed in

```
/Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the output of `which phonegap` ?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek nothing, literally nothing

Comment: Do you have `/Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules` in your `PATH`? If not, try to add it.

Comment: Or You can make a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/phonegap` to the existing phonegap executable.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I have /Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/. is this enough?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/phonegap`?

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to the odd path you've installed this software into, but the reason the shell says it can't find it is that bash (and other shells) maintain a hash table with the locations of executable binaries that have been run before.  The reason behind this is so that the shell doesn't have to actually search for it each time it needs to execute it.

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution

To force bash to re-hash the table, use 'hash -r' .

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to *link*

`/Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/phonegap`

to

`/usr/local/bin/phonegap`

### Step 1

In terminal, run

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/phonegap
```

You'll probably see something like:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 jsmith wheel 36 Mar 26 12:05 /usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /some/other/path/to/phonegap
```

If it starts with a lowercase `L` then it is a link. It's probably pointing to a file that no longer exists, so you can remove it by going

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/phonegap
```

Please be careful with `rm` it means "remove" or "delete" and there is no undo.

Then, you will need to make a new link from the existing `phonegap` to the place where it is expected to be:

```
ln -s /Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/phonegap /usr/local/bin/phonegap
```

You do *not* want to add `/Users/myUserName/.nvm/v5.8.0/lib/node_modules/` to your $PATH because that will eventually change. That's the whole reason to link them to a static path like `/usr/local/bin/`.

*Note: you may need to add `sudo` before those commands, if you get some sort of permissions error.*

(Also, sorry about the `pandoc` reference earlier. I had copied/pasted an actual example file from my computer and meant to change it and missed one.)

Comment: You will need sudo on the ln and rm commands - and did you mean pandoc?

Comment: you may need sudo depending on /usr/local/ permissions. pandoc was a typo/copy/paste relic. Thanks.